# List all products on homepage in 4 columns

Tags: layout, home, blocks, column

I'm new to magento and I want to show all store products in 4 columns on my homepage. At the moment I'm using this to show all products :

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Problem is, it's giving me 3 columns instead of 4 like it's on the category page. Is there a parameter that I can add to `block` command to render it with 4 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is **column_count**. Try this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" column_count="4"}}
```